# Get all Users with Info(LoginName,Id,Email,Title) in SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model C#

Tags: 2010, development, client-object-model, user

I have gone through this link :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee538244(v=office.14).aspx

But through this I am only able to get user details which are in groups. I am not able to get users other then groups. I need all means all users of the site in client object model.

Please help.
Thank You.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can query `SiteUserInfoList` to get all users in a site.

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://your site/");
Web web = clientContext.Web;
List siteUserInfoList = web.SiteUserInfoList;
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = "";
IEnumerable<ListItem> itemColl = clientContext.LoadQuery(siteUserInfoList.GetItems(query));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (var item in itemColl)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ID:{0}  Email:{1} Title:{2}", item.Id, item["EMail"], item["Title"]);
}
```

Comment: Yeah it worked for me... thanx mate

Comment: i am getting this error "You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource." in browser

Answer (score 1):

You can try following:

```
    Web web = context.Web;

List siteUserInfoList = web.SiteUserInfoList;  

context.Load(siteUserInfoList);

context.ExecuteQuery();
```

This way you can get all users.

Comment: .SiteUsers in not available in SharePoint 2010, it is for SP2013

Comment: Updated. Try SiteUserInfoList. It may help you.

Comment: Can you please guide me further. I tried to get Users with what you updated gave but I failed..

Comment: can i use the above code in my SP 2010 designer's custom new form.aspx page with within a javascript function?