# Bind all users of office 365 except system users using C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, user, spuser

How to bind all the users of Sharepoint(office 365) except system users like :

"System Account",

"NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users",

"_SPOCacheFull",

"YLO001_spocrwl_142_11094".

I want only custom added users like :

user1@site12345.onmicrosoft.com

user2@site12345.onmicrosoft.com

Currently I am binding all users like this:

```
using (SPSite spSite = SPContext.Current.Site)
{
    using (SPWeb web = spSite.OpenWeb())
    {
       web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

       SPUserCollection users = web.AllUsers;
       foreach (SPUser user in users)
       {
          listAllUsers.Items.Add(new ListItem(user.Name, user.LoginName)); // listAllUsers is Listbox
       }
       web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Easiest option is by checking if users has a valid email address.

Comment: Ronak Patel: inside the foreach look add a condition `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Email))` then only do `listAllUsers.Items.Add`

Answer (score 1):

The following example demonstrates how to distinguish a "regular" users in [Web.SiteUsers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.siteusers(v=office.15).aspx):

```
public static IEnumerable<User> LoadUsers(ClientContext context)
{
   var users = context.LoadQuery(context.Web.SiteUsers.Where(u => u.PrincipalType == PrincipalType.User && u.UserId.NameIdIssuer == "urn:federation:microsoftonline"));
   context.ExecuteQuery();
   return users;
}
```

where:

- [Principal.PrincipalType property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.principal.principaltype(v=office.15).aspx) - `PrincipalType.User`
  value specifies a **user** as the principal type
- [UserIdInfo.NameIdIssuer property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.useridinfo.nameidissuer(v=office.15).aspx) - configuration-agnostic
  reference to the type of the name identifier issuer, for SPO users its value: `urn:federation:microsoftonline`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://your site/");
Web web = clientContext.Web;
List siteUserInfoList = web.SiteUserInfoList;
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = "";
IEnumerable<ListItem> itemColl = clientContext.LoadQuery(siteUserInfoList.GetItems(query));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (var item in itemColl)
{
    if(item["EMail"] != null && item["EMail"] != '') 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ID:{0}  Email:{1} Title:{2}",item.Id,item["EMail"],item["Title"]);
    }
}
```

[Get all Users with Info(LoginName,Id,Email,Title) in SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model C#](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115776/get-all-users-with-infologinname-id-email-title-in-sharepoint-2010-client-obje)

Comment: I have checked the Email now..but still getting this user: YLO001_spocrwl_142_11094