# How to Get all SharePoint SpUsers from SpFarm with C#

Tags: development, server-farm, spuser

How to get a list of all users in a certain Farm in SharePoint by code? 
Is there any away to do that without must  iterate every SPgroup in every SPWeb in every WEApp?

Comment: check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115776/get-all-users-with-infologinname-id-email-title-in-sharepoint-2010-client-obje

Comment: You should be able to get all users in a farm from the user profiles. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163182.aspx

Comment: "You should be able to get all users in a farm from the user profiles": that is wrong. You may have users without user profile even if the User Profile Service is installed, and we don't know from the question, if it is installed and if the AD-sync is configured for all AD users. But one may have SharePoint users from a non-AD-based claims provider as well.
The other suggestion (the one from @Varun Verma) is restricted to a single web application, does not cover the whole farm.

Comment: For this purpose, I think varun Verma Solution could be a good one. Because I don't need any user  who is  out of profiler. But I see running my that it does't output every userProfie into sharepoint. Do you if there any MAX filter in it?

Comment: You mean the solution proposed by @user19952, don't you? I'm not aware of any max. filter there, but could you please share the code you have? The user profiles you do see on the UI, should be all returned by code. However, if there is no automatic synchronization with the full AD, there migth be users without profile.

Answer (score 0):

static void Main(string[] args)
    {

```
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server"]))
    {
        ServerContext context = ServerContext.GetContext(site);
        UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context,true);

        foreach (UserProfile profile in profileManager)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(profile[PropertyConstants.AccountName]);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not iterate through members of the `SPGroup` objects and `SPWeb` objects.

You should iterate through the web applications, their site collections and the users of each site collections as shown in the code below:

```
var webServices = SPFarm.Local.Services.Where(s => s is SPWebService).Select(s => s as SPWebService);

foreach (SPWebService service in webServices)
{
  foreach (SPWebApplication wa in service.WebApplications)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("=== Web application: {0}", wa.Name);
    var siteIds = wa.Sites.Select(s => s.ID);
    foreach (var siteId in siteIds)
    {
      using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteId))
      {
        Console.WriteLine("------ Site Url: {0}", site.Url);
        foreach (SPUser user in site.RootWeb.SiteUsers)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(user.LoginName);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note, that it displays users for the Central Administration web application, and for each MySite as well (if you have any). I don't know if it is desired.

Comment: UserProfiler result  output could be duplicated or more??

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question, and what you mean on 'UserProfiler'. There is nothing to do with the User Profiles in my answer. If you meant users, yes, my code can (and probably will) output the login names duplicated. If one does not like that, can create a List<String> and add the login name to the list only if it is not already contained in the list.

Comment: Thank you so much. Another question if you can help me. Is there any way to  get (from SPUser obj)  all permission taht it has on every SecureObject in the farm?

Comment: Direct from the SPUser you cannot access this info. However, if you iterate through all of the securable objects in your farm, it should be possible. Since this might require a really long time, I would not recommend this approach, only for reporting processes running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code

```
 using ( SPWeb site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web))
                {
                    SPServiceContext serverContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
                    UserProfileManager userProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(serverContext);
                    Console.WriteLine(userProfileManager.Count);
                    Console.ReadLine();

            }
```